# Managing global data in a namespaced, multitenant Appengine application

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb

I'm designing a multitenant system using namespaces.

Users authenticate via OpenID, and a User model is saved in Cloud Datastore. Users will be grouped into Organizations, also modeled in the database. Application data needs to be partitioned by organization.

So the idea is to map namespaces to "Organizations".

When a user logs in, their Organization is looked up and saved in a session.

WSGI middleware inspects the session and sets the namespace accordingly.

My question relates to how best to manage switching between data that is "global" (i.e. User and Organization) and application data (namespaced by organization)

My current approach is to use  python decorators and context managers to temporarily switch to the global namepace for operations that access such global data. e.g.

```
standard_datastore_op()

with global_namespace():
    org = Organization.query(Organization.key=org_key)

another_standard_datastore_op(org.name)
```

or

```
@global_namespace
def process_login(user_id):
    user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
```

This also implies that models have cross-namespace KeyProperties:

```
class DomainData(ndb.Model): # in the current user's namespace

    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    foreign_org = ndb.KeyProperty(Organization) #in the "global" namespace
```

Does this seem a reasonable approach? It feels a little fragile to me, but I suspect that is because I'm new to working with namespaces in App Engine. My alternative idea is to extract all "global" data from Cloud Datastore into external web-service but I'd rather  avoid that if possible.

Advice gratefully received. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Did you find out better solution? I have the same architecture and it's a pain to figure out how to use e.g. User model in global (for auth) and in private (for foreign keys) namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators is a perfectly fine approach, which also has the benefit of clearly labeling which functions operate outside of organization-specific namespace bounds.

```
def global_namespace(global_namespace_function):
  def wrapper():
    # Save the current namespace.
    previous_namespace = namespace_manager.get_namespace()

    try:
        # Empty string = default namespace, change to whatever you want to use as 'global'
        global_namespace = ''
        # Switch to 'global' namespace
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(global_namespace)

        # Run code that requires global namespace
        global_namespace_function()
    finally:
        # Restore the saved namespace.
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(previous_namespace)

  return wrapper
```

On a related note, we also have documentation on using [namespaces for multitenenacy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy).